# How to flag a user who keeps posting the same question and deleting the old one?

Tags: support, questions, flags, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I know when flagging a question there's an option to select "duplicate", but what about when a user doesn't get the response they want so they keep posting a new one and deleting the old one?

Is there anyway admins can see the user deleted a similar question?

It's really annoying to see this and I'm hoping there's a way to stop people from doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No action is needed.

Users who keep on deleting and re-posting the same question will be hit with the [automatic  question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Self-deleted questions supposedly contribute significantly to the question-ban for this specific reason.

---

So it's a self-correcting problem. (Intentional by design.)

I'd say flagging for moderator attention is not necessary unless the user starts using multiple accounts to evade the ban and continue to spam the site.

Answer (score 5):

Moderators can see deleted questions on a user's profile, so simply flag the question, explain the situation, and the moderator will be able to see the deleted question and take appropriate action.